# Tables are not created in the SpringBoot 3.2.2 application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to generate tables based on entities. The application starts correctly, none of tables are created. What's wrong?

I'm using springboot 3.2.2, java 17 and mysql

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"> <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> <parent> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId> <version>3.2.2</version> <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository --> </parent> <groupId>it.newEra</groupId> <artifactId>BookingYourLuggage</artifactId> <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> <name>BookingYourLuggage</name> <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description> <properties> <java.version>17</java.version> </properties> <dependencies> <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

My main

```
package it.newEra.yourLuggage;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication; import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication; import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;

@SpringBootApplication public class BookingYourLuggageApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(BookingYourLuggageApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

My entity class

```
package it.newEra.yourLuggage.model;

import java.math.BigDecimal; import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType; import jakarta.persistence.Column; import jakarta.persistence.Entity; import jakarta.persistence.FetchType; import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue; import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType; import jakarta.persistence.Id; import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany; import lombok.AllArgsConstructor; import lombok.Getter; import lombok.Setter;

@Entity @Getter @Setter @AllArgsConstructor public class Drawer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "drawer_type")
private String drawerType;

@Column(name = "drawer_prive")
private BigDecimal drawerPrice;

@Column(name = "is_booked")
private boolean isBooked = false;

}
```

My application.yml

```
server:
   port: 9192
spring:
   datasource:
      username: root
      password: Password.
      url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/booking_your_luggage?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
   jpa:
      show_sql: true
      properties:
         hibernate:
            ddl-auto: update
            format-sql: true
   servlet:
      multipart:
         max-file-size: 5MB
         max-request-size: 5MB
         file-size-threshold: 2MB
```

I have searched online that updating the dependencies or maybe a database naming problem, however I cannot find the solution to my own problem.

I'm going crazy!

Answer (score 1):

looks like you missed just a valid property setup for the hibernate.
Please try next config (updated from the original):

```
server:
    port: 9192
spring:
    datasource:
        username: root
        password: Password.
        url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/booking_your_luggage?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
        driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    jpa:
        show_sql: true
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: update
        properties:
            hibernate:
                format-sql: true
    servlet:
        multipart:
            max-file-size: 5MB
            max-request-size: 5MB
            file-size-threshold: 2MB
```

Please compare it with your original yaml and you'll find the correct `ddl-auto` property setup. Also please check the indentation level.

NOTE: This [Spring Boot How to data access](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-access.jpa-properties) link may be useful.